# Next Three month Rolling sum of sales

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Im struggling in script logic below is my data set and  want to sum the below data based on next three months**

[image: Data set]

[image: Desired result from the given data set]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: How do you get from the value in the first dataset to the second? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can you add sample data as text which we can use as opposed to images which we can't.

Comment: And please add expected outcome.

Comment: I disagree with close votes , voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write your query like following.

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(CAST(SUBSTRING(T1.YearMonth, 1, 4) AS INT), 
            CAST(SUBSTRING(T1.YearMonth, 5, 2) AS INT), 1) YearMonthDt
        ,Sales
        ,YearMonth
    FROM @table T1
    )
SELECT T1.YearMonth
    ,T2.YearMonth
    ,T2.sales
FROM CTE T1
INNER JOIN CTE T2 ON DATEDIFF(mm, T2.YearMonthDt, T1.YearMonthDt) <= 3
ORDER BY T1.YearMonth
```

**[Working Demo](https://rextester.com/CDBR41741)**

Answer (score 0):

Your title describes a rolling sum.  Your sample data is simply taking a maximum.  The following does both.

Hmmm . . . I think `row_number()` can be a big help here:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by yearmonth) as seqnum
      from yourtable t
     )
select t1.yearmonth, max(t2.yearmonth) as last_mont_max, sum(t2.sales) as rolling_sum,
       max(t2.sales) as value
from t t1 cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3)) n(n) join
     t t2
     on t2.seqnum >= t1.seqnum and
        t2.seqnum <= t1.seqnum + n.n
group by t1.yearmonth, n.n;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04c58b/3) is a db<>fiddle

If you just wanted the rolling sum on each row (not what your results show), then it is much simpler:

```
select t.*,
       sum(sales) over (order by yearmonth
                        rows between current row and 2 following)
                       ) as value
from yourtable t;
```